# How do you append text to matches using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all occurrences of `~(.+?)` with `(.+?).not()`.

The problem is, `str.replace(/~\(.+?\)/, ".not()")` of course also replaces the text matched by `.+?`. In a perfect world I would do this:

`str.replace(/~\(.+?\)/, match + ".not()")`.

What is the equivalent for this in JS? I would prefer not to loop over the matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may backreference matches from the search pattern in the replacement, with `$1 $2 $3` etc. for the first match group, second match group, and so on.  When there is no capturing group, you can use `$&` for the whole pattern match to avoid adding extra parens.

So in this case you probably want:

```
str.replace(/~(\(.+?\))/, "$1.not()")
```

Note: other regex engines use `$0` for whole pattern match, so be careful.  Backreference syntax varies quite a bit, actually -- sed prefers the notation `\1 \2 \3` instead of `$1 $2 $3`

Comment: There is no capturing group here.

Comment: oops, yeah - updated to use the 'entire match' backreference $0

Comment: oh javascript, you just have to be different.  js uses $& instead of $0, sorry. updated!

Comment: wait, do you want to keep the ~ in the final output or get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) around the part you want to retain and then reference the group # inside of the replacement call. Also, the `g` modifier is needed to replace all occurrences.

```
var r = '~(foo) and ~(bar) and ~(baz)'.replace(/~(\(.+?\))/g, '$1.not()')
console.log(r) //=> '(foo).not() and (bar).not() and (baz).not()'
```

Comment: add the missing ~ symbol and you get best answer.
Nevermind, McClure fixed his first =(. lol

Comment: @KthProg symbol added, why is it not included in your pattern in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a backreference:

```
/~(\(.+?\))/
```

Example here: https://www.regex101.com/r/cE9nC5/1

Comment: Any you can guarantee that link will be available for reference a few years from now? Sorry but you need to actually answer the question.